# Can't create a condition for null values in an array?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, expression, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I am using linq expression trees to build a query.

My array:

```
string[] { null, null }
```

condition I want to implement:

```
x == null ? null : x.ToLower()
```

My linq expression looks like this:

```
{Param_0 => value(System.String[]).Any(Param_1 => (Param_0.FirstName.ToLower() == IIF((Param_1 == null), null, Param_1.ToLower())))}
```

This is my first attempt and I can't seem to find the correct way to do it

```
Constant = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(Constant, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string))), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)), Expression.Call(Constant, "ToLower", null));
```

The expected result is to be able to call `.ToLower()` on elements that are not null

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want an expression that represents a function call with input a string, and output a string.

```
Expression<Func<string, string>>
```

How about a Lambda expression?

```
Expression<Func<string, string>> myExpression = (x) => (x==null) ? null : x.ToLower();
```

This expression can be used in a Queryable Select statement, like below:

```
IQueryable<string> myItems = new List<sring>()
{
    "Abc",
    null,
    "DEF",
    null,
    "gHI",
}
.AsQueryable();

IQueryable<string> myLowerCaseItems = myItems.Select(myExpression);
foreach (string item in myLowerCaseItems)
{
    if (item == null)
        Console.WriteLine("<null>");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This yields the following output:

abc
   
   def
   
   ghi